# What do the distributions contain?

Tags: miktex, texlive, distributions

Generally, the distributions – TeXLive, MacTeX, MiKTeX and proTeXt – contain packages & classes. **But is there anything else?**

Comment: "packages" and "classes" are latex tex files, distributions contain the programs (tex,luatex,xetex,,bibtex, makeindex...) fonts, documentation, bibtex styles, and a host of other things.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  But the large size of the TeXLive from packages

Comment: So the engines come with distributions not with editors?

Comment: @MamounMohammed not at all. All of texmf-dist/tex so that is latex packages and classes, all of plain tex  context, .. comes to less than 0.5Gb the fonts directory is 3.1G so more than 6 times as much doc is 3G as well

Comment: @MamounMohammed of course yes an editor is just an editor if you install an editor you do not have tex at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But why do fonts have so much size?

Comment: (a) because Chinese has lots of characters and (b) there are lots (thousands) of fonts to choose from.

Comment: the texlive 2021 texmf-dist/fonts directory contains 124075 files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Then the difference in size between TeXLive and MiKTeX, comes from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120835/discussion-between-mamoun-mohammed-and-david-carlisle).